# Using maven to create two artifacts with overlapping classes

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I have a maven pom that creates an artifact, let's call it everything.jar.

I would like to copy a subset of the classes in everything.jar into another jar, let's call it mini.jar.

What's the best way to structure my maven pom(s) to produce two jar files, one called mini.jar with just a few classes, and the other everything.jar with everything in mini plus some additional classes, without actually making copies of the source?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it the other way around.

Create a multi - module project:

```
      root
    /  |   \
mini extra everything
```

- **mini** contains the core stuff
- **extra** has a dependency to mini and defines the additional classes
- **everything** has a dependency to both and uses the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create a
  combined jar from the two other
  projects (you can also do that from
  inside the **extra** project, but I'd
  call that less elegant)

**Reference:**

- [`shade:shade` mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html)
- [Selecting Contents for Uber JAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)